# Google function removeDuplicates only works with exact case match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets document that has list of names and email addresses.  I'm trying to "removeDuplicates" if the email address is duplicated on another row within the same sheet.  The script works fine but ONLY IF THE CASE IS AN EXACT MATCH.  I would like for my script to work regardless of the case of the letters.  For example removeDuplicate if "JOHN@JOHN.COM" and "john@john.com" are both on the sheet.  My current script is as follows:

```
    function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[9] == newData[j][9]){
  duplicate = true;
    }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix for someone who understands how this works.  Unfortunately that person is not me.  I have very little experience with writing scripts and rely heavily on what I am able to find on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I would handle this is to convert each value to either upper or lower case and compare those values. So change your comparision from: `if(row[9] == newData[j][9])` to `if(row[9].toLowerCase() == newData[j][9].toLowerCase())`.

Comment: Thanks but I must have done something wrong because that didn't work for me.  I loaded up some sample data and played around with the case but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try using trim() in case there is some extra white space in some values.